# Haskell pattern matching in LLVM-general-pure library

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am new to Haskell and I am using the llvm-general-ure-3.5.1.0 library:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general-pure-3.5.1.0/docs/

There is a basic block data type, Named and name data type:

```
data BasicBlock = BasicBlock Name [Named Instruction] (Named Terminator)
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show, Typeable, Data)

data Named a 
  = Name := a
  | Do a

data Name 
    = Name String -- ^ a string name 
    | UnName Word -- ^ a number for a nameless thing
```

The problem I am having is pattern matching against Named Instruction.

My code looks like this:

```
executeInstruction :: Named Instruction -> Memory -> Memory
executeInstruction inst mem = 
  case inst of
    Add nsw nuw op0 op1 meta -> undefined
```

This gives me an error message that I expect, my types don't match of Named Instruction vs Instruction.

So I want to strip off the Named and have just an Instruction left.

```
stripN :: Named Instruction -> Instruction
stripN (Name n inst) = inst
```

This gives this error:

Constructor `Name' should have 1 argument, but has been given 2
    In the pattern: Name n inst

I understand the error.   But I don't see how to get just an Instruction from a Named Instruction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
executeInstruction :: Named Instruction -> Memory -> Memory
executeInstruction (name := inst) mem = 
     undefined
executeInstruction (Do inst) mem = 
     undefined
```

Above, `inst :: Instruction`, so you can also pattern match on that.

If you plan to do the exact same thing in both branches, you might want to define a projection, first:

```
getInst :: Named Instruction -> Instruction
getInst (_ := i) = i
getInst (Do i)   = i

executeInstruction :: Named Instruction -> Memory -> Memory
executeInstruction namedInst mem = case getInst namedInst of
   Add nsw nuw op0 op1 meta -> undefined
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: One quick question, what is the := operator?

Comment: @user2297034 I actually have no idea, I just found about it in your question: `data Named a = Name := a | Do a`. So, `:=` is one of the constructors of `Named`. I guess that a `Named Instruction` is just a plain insn (`Do insn`) or a labelled insns with a name (`name := insn`). I don't know how this is exactly used in the library.